# Meteor deploy Iron:Router "oops looks like there's no route on the client or the server for url"

Tags: deployment, meteor, iron-router

When I deploy using "meteor deploy mysite.com" or "meteor deploy mysite.meteor.com" I get the error: "oops looks like there's no route on the client or the server for url".  I don't have this issue on localhost.  I don't see anything unusual on "meteor logs mysite.com"

Basically, if the user is not logged in then the page should be redirected to the welcome page.  Here is a snippet of the code.  Any ideas?

```
Router.onBeforeAction(function () {
  if (!Meteor.user() && !Meteor.loggingIn()) {
    this.redirect("/welcome");
  } else {
    this.next();
  }
}, {
  except: [
    "entrySignIn",
    "entrySignUp",
    "entrySignOut",
    "welcomePage"
  ]
});

Router.route("/", {
    template: "homePage",
    action: function() {
        if (Meteor.user()) {
            this.render("homePage");
        } else {
            this.redirect("/welcome");
        }
    }
});
 Router.route('/welcome', {layoutTemplate: 'welcomePage'});
```

Comment: where do you define the route for `/welcome`?

Comment: I left it out in the question by mistake. I edited the question to include the route definition. Router.route('/welcome', {layoutTemplate: 'welcomePage'});

Comment: @ChristianFritz: Check where the actual definition is.  If it's in your server directory / inside an isServer{} block then the client won't see it.