# Ironrouter says route doesn't exist when it does ("Oops, looks like there's no route on the client")

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I am trying to display a URL with a paramter in Meteor like so:

```
    http://localhost:3000/test/123
```

My routes.js contains the following:

```
    Router.route('/test/:x1', function () {
      this.render('test', {
        to:"main",
        param:this.params.x1
      });
    });
```

and main.html the following template

```
   <template name="test">
     <h2>Test {{param}}</h2>
   </template>
```

However, when I access http://localhost:3000/test/123 I get the following error message:

```
   Oops, looks like there's no route on the client or the server for url:     
   "http://localhost:3000/test/123."
```

I have pretty muched copied this verbatim from the ironrouter docs. Other issues Stackoverflow, like [Meteor deploy Iron:Router "oops looks like there's no route on the client or the server for url"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29830768/meteor-deploy-ironrouter-oops-looks-like-theres-no-route-on-the-client-or-the) does not seem to address exactly this issue

Comment: I'm assuming you are using Meteor 1.3. Did you add your route file in client's main.js file?

Comment: This is strange. I copied your code and it works. In which directory did you put your `routes.js` file?

Comment: Faysal: No, just added routes.js to the client directory. Should it be imported in the main.js with an  import './routes.js'; statement? I tried that, but it didn't change things.

Comment: Tdm: Routes.js is in the client directory. And it's Meteor 1.3.2.4

Answer (score 0):

So I solved the problem in a somewhat inconclusive way. As was pointed out by one of the commentors, the code in itself works, but not in my application. So I created a new application and transferred the code, line by line, to the new application, and it kept on working. Not all the code was displayed above, but the parts that were omitted should not have affected this problem. I still don't know though what triggered the problem in the first place.